# Is there a speed benefit to specifying a context when selecting by id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Assuming there are no duplicate IDs in the DOM and `$parent` is a jQuery object containing a single element that is the parent of `#myID`

```
var $el = $("#myID");
```

vs

```
var $el = $("#myID", $parent);  //Faster or slower?
```

Is there a speed difference between the two of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a speed benefit to specifying a context when selecting by id in jQuery?

No, it actually makes things slower (or at least, it *can*), because jQuery has a special path for simple ID selectors and uses `document.getElementById` — but only if you don't give a context. So giving a context will slow things down (or at least, *might* slow things down), because jQuery won't be able to take that shortcut. The relevant check is on line 135 of the current uncompressed jQuery release (v1.7.1).

Comment: Wouldn't that mean specifying a context then is slower, Not the same?

Comment: @C.J.: I was just reading the code and saw the exception bypassing it for cases where you give a context (I had assumed it ignored the context, but of course that would be wrong), so I was fixing it as you commented. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the lookup is fast no matter how many elements have to be checked since browsers use hash tables for ID lookups which can perform lookups in `O(1)`.

Specifying a context might even slow things down since after the initial lookup a check is necessary to see if the found element is a child of the context element - and this check will most likely involve iterating over all parent elements of the found element up to the root element to see if the context is one of these elements. Now take a context that is not a single element and it will be even more expensive.